# C++ Get Password from text file

Tags: c++

I have a text file that looks like:

```
username abc
password abc123
```

How can I get just the actual user password (i.e. abc123) and return it?

Currently, I have:

```
read.seekg(9);
getline(read, usernameFile, ' ');
getline(read, passwordFile, ' ');

return passwordFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string user;
std::string password;
std::string usernameFile; //Username from file
std::string passwordFile;

std::ifstream read(username + ".txt", std::ios::in);

while (read >> user >> username >> password >> passwordFile)
    {
        return passwordFile;
    }
```

For some reason, I made it more difficult and I thought using a while loop would only work in a scenario where it was attaining the same data over again from a text file such as if the text file read:

```
Account #1    Person    Amount
1              PJ       100.00
2              MJ       50000.00
```

But the while loop I used above resolved the matter.